# Automatically select single line in WPF Form Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to automatically select an entire line in a multiline WPF textbox. So if the user clicks on a word on Line 3, the entirety of Line 3 is selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPF TextBox SelectionStart on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart.aspx)

The easiest way is to take this value and iterate backwards in the content of the TextBox until count hits 0 or `\n \r\n \r` and then forwards until text size or `\n \r\n \r`. After that set the current selection to these boundaries.

Comment: But I'm not trying to highlight the entire textbox. Just the line clicked on. So if I iterate back to 0, I'll get too much.

Comment: Back to 0 `OR` newline. If you don't catch 0, you get errors thrown if you select the first line of text. The same for the last line.